# Error message "Undefined reference error to" in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting an undefined reference for one of the class methods in C++. The error is "undefined reference to 'Department::getNameabi:cxx11' and other many lines for each method call of department.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

#include "department.h"

using namespace std;

void addDepartment();
void writeToFile();
void showArt();
void removeDepartment();

vector <Department> departments;


int main()
{
    int choice;
    do
    {
        cout << "1)Add asset \t 2)Remove Asset \t 3)Departmental Options \t 4)Quit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: addDepartment();
                    break;

            case 2: removeDepartment();
                    break;

            case 3: //showReport();
                    break;
        }

        addDepartment();
    } while(choice != 4);
}

void showArt()
{
    cout << "ASSET MANGEMENT" << endl;
}

void addDepartment()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter department name" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    vector<Department>::iterator it;
    int flag = 0;

    for(it = departments.begin(); it!=departments.end(); it++)
    {

        if (it->getName().compare(name) == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            it->addAsset();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0)
    {
        Department temp(name);
        temp.addAsset();
        departments.push_back(temp);
    }
}

void removeDepartment()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter department name" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    vector<Department>::iterator it;
    int flag = 0;

    for(it = departments.begin(); it!=departments.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->getName().compare(name) == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            it->removeAsset();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0)
    {
        cout << "No such department puta!" << endl;
    }
}
```

My department's header file is as follows:

```
#ifndef DEPARTMENT_H
#define DEPARTMENT_H
#endif

#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "computer.h"
#include "software.h"
using namespace std;

class Department
{
    string name;
    vector<Computer> computers;
    vector<Software> softwares;

    void addComputer();
    void addSoftware();

    public:
        Department(string);
        void addAsset();
        void removeAsset();
        string getName();
};
```

#### Error

```
bipgen@genbox:~/asset-management$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
/tmp/ccvu6doW.o: In function `addDepartment()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `Department::getName[abi:cxx11]()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `Department::addAsset()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x220): undefined reference to `Department::Department(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::a
llocator<char> >)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x23b): undefined reference to `Department::addAsset()'
/tmp/ccvu6doW.o: In function `removeDepartment()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x392): undefined reference to `Department::getName[abi:cxx11]()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3d8): undefined reference to `Department::removeAsset()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 12):

All of `Department`'s member functions are only declared, not defined.

This means that the compiler acknowledges their existence and compiles `main.cpp`, where they are called, without any trouble.

When the compiler has done its job, it's the **linker**'s turn to "glue" the functions' implementations to their calls. But it doesn't find the implementations, so it rightfully complains.

---

Now, I guess you didn't just declare the member functions and forgot to define them. You very likely have the definitions in a separate file called `department.cpp` which looks like this:

```
#include "department.h"

void Department::addSoftware() {
    // implementation
}

Department::Department(string) {
    // implementation
}

void Department::addAsset() {
    // implementation
}

void Department::removeAsset() {
    // implementation
}

string Department::getName() {
    // implementation
}
```

You probably also thought that the inclusion of `department.h` by `main.cpp` would somehow magically pull in the code from `department.cpp`.

But that's not how C++ (or a typical C++ tool chain, for that matter) works. The linker doesn't know about any implementations originating from source code in other files unless you tell it. As a matter of fact, not even the compiler knows about them in your case.

You need to compile `department.cpp` and pass the resulting binary code to the linker. The quick way to do so would be:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp department.cpp
```

Sooner or later, you will want a more elaborate process, in which each `*.cpp` file is compiled into an `*.o` file and the `*.o` files are then passed to the linker, all of that happening within a Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Department class implementation included into compile?

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp department.cpp
```

Comment: I have included "departmen.h" in my main class